Google sheet API pricing
I have in mind to develop an Android app using Google Sheet API to store some data. Each user of the app will have his own Google Sheet document and the content will remain private (so, me, as the app developer will not have access to the data).
I have seen that there are some quotas for the use of Google sheet API. I'm wondering how they are calculated:

Are they calculated separately for each user of my app?
Or are they evaluated for the total of accesses done by all the users of my app?

I hope that it is the first one. Otherwise a user doing lot of traffic could impact other users of my app. Obviously I prefer that it only impacts himself.
Thanks for your advices

Quota limits
There are two different types of quotas User based and project based.
Here is an image of my current quota allotment.

user based quotas
The ones that end in per minute per user are the user based ones.  These are basically flood protection it ensures that no one user of can flood the system.
project based quotas
The other quotas are project based.  These limit what your project can do as a whole across all of your users.  The good news is these can be extended.  All you have to do is apply for an extension and google will if they see fit give you more project quota.
quota extension
Tips for requesting more quota.

Describe your use case well but dont go over the top.
Wait until you are around 80% of the current quota before applying
Depending upon the api it can take some time maybe a couple of weeks
I have never heard of them charging anyone money for a quota extension.

